# How to validate simple quotes in an input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I'm finding something like htmlentitles in HTML, that makes all the user input in an absolute string, I make a consult with that string and if I write in the input a simple quote make to the program a syntax error, how can I fix it?

Comment: I solved with try-except

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes if you don't have any single quote in your string:

```
>>> a = 'hello "world"'
>>> print(a)
hello "world"
```

Comment: Or you can escape the character using \, e.g. 
`s = 'it\'s an escaped apostrophe'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape all quotes and apostrophes `"Isn\'t escaping easy"` or use the type of quotes (double "" or single '') that aren't in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3 quotes: `"""'asd'"123'"""`